# How does WEKA normalize attributes?

Tags: java, machine-learning, data-mining, weka

Suppose I input to WEKA some dataset and set a normalization filter for the attributes so the values be between 0 and 1. Then suppose the normalization is done by dividing on the maximum value, and then the model is built. Then what happens if I deploy the model and in the new instances to be classified an instance has a feature value that is larger than the maximum in the training set. How such a situation is handled? Does it just take 1 or does it then take more than 1? Or does it throw an exception?

Comment: Was this answer helpful?

Answer (score 4):

The documentation doesn't specify this for filters in general.So it must depend on the filter. I looked at the source code of `weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.Normalize` which I assume you are using, and I don't see any bounds checking in it.

The actual scaling code is in the [Normalize.convertInstance() method](https://svn.cms.waikato.ac.nz/svn/weka/trunk/weka/src/main/java/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/Normalize.java):

```
value = (vals[j] - m_MinArray[j]) / (m_MaxArray[j] - m_MinArray[j])
              * m_Scale + m_Translation;
```

Barring any (unlikely) additional checks outside this method I'd say that it will scale to a value greater than 1 in the situation that you describe. To be 100% sure your best bet is to write a testcase, invoke the filter yourself, and find out. With libraries that haven't specified their working in the Javadoc, you never know what the next release will do. So if you greatly depend on a particular behaviour, it's not a bad idea to write an automated test that regression-tests the behaviour of the library.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same questions as you said. I did as follows and may this method can help you:

I suppose you use the `weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.Normalize` to normalize your data.

as Erwin Bolwidt said, weka use

```
value = (vals[j] - m_MinArray[j]) / (m_MaxArray[j] - m_MinArray[j])
          * m_Scale + m_Translation;
```

to normalize your attribute.

Don't forget that the Normalize class has this two method:

```
public double[] getMinArray()
public double[] getMaxArray()
```

Which Returns the calculated minimum/maximum  values for the attributes in the data.

And you can store the minimum/maximum  values. And then use the formula to normalize your data by yourself.

Remember you can set the attribute in `Instance` class, and you can classify your result by `Evaluation.evaluationForSingleInstance`

I 'll give you the link later,  may this help you.
Thank you